# See Publication Date for Items in Sitecore

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8

I'm trying to figure out how to know when an Item was published in Sitecore.  I've looked at the History table in SQL Server and I see when the Item was changed, and also when it moved through every step in the workflow.  But I don't see anything that looks like a "Publication" event.

Thanks...!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately  you can't get a published date. You need to implement a custom way to track when items are published.
Please check this blog post:

http://sitecoreskills.blogspot.ro/2014/04/first-and-last-publish-dates-in-sitecore.html

Comment: Thanks.  That helps.  I really need to track the publication history of the item from birth to death.  Could I perhaps adapt the code in that blog post to add a custom record to the History table (instead of updating those 2 custom fields)? Or would this be a bad idea?

Answer (score 1):

If tracking the item published date using the History Table, note that the History Table is cleaned-up every 4hrs by default. So, you may end up having no values for the item.

Normally, once an item has been modified, it is inserted into the publish queue table. You may instead track the last published that occurred. You may refer to my blog post: https://hishaamn.wordpress.com/2015/10/25/last-published-timestamp-on-sitecore-login-page/

Thanks